# iOS: UI glitch after animation xcode 9

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have seen this weird green lines after the animation. any idea why this happen? (I think I didn't see it before, it happens some time after xcode 9)

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.noticeBarHeight?.constant = 42
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

    delayOnMainThread(3, block: { [weak self] in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self?.noticeBarHeight?.constant = 0
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    })
```

[image: Glitch]

Comment: may be due to delayOnMainThread ? ,  i  am not sure . but you can try another one option . After complete the First animation , perform the second animation in completion block of first animation . And in second animation you can put some delay also. just try it .

Comment: Why don't you use an animation with initial delay and start it from the completion block of the first animation? A keyframe animation should also be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks GOPAL VASANI and macmoonshine. The initial delay in UIView animation has that problem and that's why I try the delayOnMainThread thing.   key frame animation is a great idea and it bypasses the problem for now. But Im still curious why this happen